# Markers and Clusters are flashed/redraw when zoom is changing [googlemaps/js-markerclusterer]

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I reviewed this example http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f5baj1uq/:
it uses https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markerclustererplus/2.1.4/markerclusterer.js
I love it because I zoom markers and clusters and them are not redrawn.
[MarkerCluster-Ok.webm](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/67704982/192104052-b6b67bc5-cc0b-44a8-bed3-1b862caaf7fe.webm)

But checking the last version `https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/public/defaults/` I see that all markers and clusters are drawn for example in each zoom changing giving a bad user experience because unnecessary markers and clusters are drawing again.
[MarkerCluster-Ko.webm](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/67704982/192104133-b37be700-7e72-44f8-898c-b9b8bb91f1cb.webm)

Is there an option in the last version to avoid flash/redraw effect in markers and clusters?
Thanks for your response.